# Insert all records of one special field of a table to another using ADO.net in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

How it is possible to insert all records of one special field of a table to another table (plus providing data for another fields) without repeating several times insert command for each record (putting it inside a while loop)
I would like to know the possible methods for this case(even if I have to put inside a loop).

For example:

```
Table1(idTable1, name , family) 
Table2(idTable2, idTable1, address, telephone)
```

I want to copy all records of the field `idTable1` from table1 to field `idTable1` of Table2 plus address and telephone data.

Comment: You are talking about in memory `DataTable` or actual table in database?

Comment: If you are talking about DataTable then go to the following link. 
[Adding a Column of one datatable to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323007/adding-a-column-of-one-datatable-to-another/1323053#1323053)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 ( ..., ..., ..., ...)
SELECT ..., ..., 'Some extra colums'
FROM tbl1
( WHERE if needed)
```

Comment: I want to insert into second fields of tbl2 from id column of tbl1, and the first and the other field must be fill using '{0}'.... . Could you please let me know how I can use select command just for second field. query = string.Format("insert into tbl2 (year_id,element_id,element_grade,element_desc,element_estimated_grade,element_estimated_desc) values('{0}',select id from tbl1,'{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", yearID, 0, "", 0, "");